# Cordova plugins undefined with IONIC framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I'm in trouble and found no answer, my object windows.cordova.plugin this undefined need to access the keyboard, apparently my code is correct. I use Visual Studio 2015 and Last version cordova(5.3) and IONIC(1.1).

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })

  .state('home-page', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Comment: Do you use `$ ionic serve` to test your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error, I created the project in the wrong way , creating a new project " cord apache " in Visual Studio 2015 community and added the " NuGet " the IONIC , then found the solution as follows I created a project by cmd for command iONIC "start ionic ... " . This generated a doubt can not create a direct IONIC project in Visual Studio 2015? equal the cord Apache ???

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the plugin is well installed in the platform inspecting the file

```
/plugins/{platform}.json
```

for exemple for android the file is

```
/plugins/android.json
```

and check the value of ***installed_plugins***

```
...
"installed_plugins": {
        "com.ionic.keyboard": {
            ...
        },
...
}
```

Comment: but I have other installed plugins that lets you install Visual But my object " windows.cordova.plugin " is undefined can not even find the installed plugins

Comment: Good answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks right. How did you test your application? Did you run on an actual device? If you tested on the browser, it will be undefined. If the problem persists, try to remove and add the plugin again:

```
$cordova plugin remove ionic-plugin-keyboard
$cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
$cordova prepare
```

Then try running on your device.

Comment: I  run on an actual device

Comment: You might want to check "package.json" if it shows the same plugin you installed for the keyboard.